# how to show label for user meta in user profile ultimate member

Tags: wordpress, user-profile, ultimate-member

i try to show user data in user profile
but in profile page not show tab and not show data, It's show only profile photo.
i want to click view profile from menu user in admin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrdFo.png)

after click i want to show profile for that user.

i user ultimate member plugin
i go to forms > profile and add filed but it's not show
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e2B1.png)

so, i add fields to meta but it's show only data not show label
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIGfQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCsf2.png)

how to show label for user meta or how show filed in form builder?

help me, please!!

Answer (score 0):

now, i can use this for custom label for meta
but i can't pull label name from ultimate member

```html
add_filter('um_show_meta_item_html','um_show_meta_item_html_custom',10, 2);
function um_show_meta_item_html_custom( $html, $args ) {
    $feildName = array(
                            "id_card" => "ID Card"
                            
                      );
    $htmlNew .= '<div class="meta-title-name">';
    $htmlNew .= $feildName[$args];  
    $htmlNew .= '</div>';
    $htmlNew .= '<div class="meta-title-value">'.$html.'</div>';
    return $htmlNew;
}
```